# C++/WinRT UWP app using asynchronous .dlls and Windows Runtime Component

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, marshalling, c++-winrt

I'm currently trying to extend the functionality of the NVIDIA CloudXR client app for HoloLens2 to perform ArUco marker tracking. The C++/WinRT app of the client app is initialized using MTA. The CloudXR functionality is provided using two .dlls.
I've included the ArUco tracking capability in a separate Windows Runtime Component which the client app is referencing to. My app starts up connecting to the server and starts receiving frames, however as soon as I start up the HL2 camera using:

```
concurrency::create_task(_holoLensMediaFrameSourceGroup->StartAsync()).then(
        [&]()
        {
            _holoLensMediaFrameSourceGroupStarted = true;
        });
```

my client stops receiving frames. Instead of `Success` my LatchFrame function returns `Frame_Not_Ready`. Because of that I'm assuming that the connection to the server still is open.
I've defined all ref classes in my Windows Runtime Component as agile by default. So `ThreadingModel` should be set to `Both` and `MarshallingType` to `Agile`.
I'm assuming that some background thread of the CloudXR .dlls somehow gets blocked.
Does anyone have an idea of what's going on or how I could resolve my issue? I've been stuck here for weeks and i can't seem to figure out where things go wrong.

I've also tried using Vuforia tracking using .lib instead of a Windows Runtime Component which led to the same issue.

Comment: If this is indeed a threading issue, have you tried switching to a different runtime? The ConcRT is pretty dated, and C++/WinRT provides adapters for C++20 coroutines. Do things change when calling `co_await _holoLensMediaFrameSourceGroup->StartAsync();` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `co_await _holoLensMediaFrameSourceGroup->StartAsync();` causes an error but as far as I understood it should be equal to `create_task`. So you mean I should call my LatchFrame function in a coroutine? I've tried it, however this causes my app to not receive any frames, nor to start my camera.